# Exclude post type with pre_get_posts?

Tags: pre-get-posts, tax-query

I am using pre_get_posts for a custom taxonomy archive display. Now I added a post type 'photo' sharing the same taxonomy with default post type. How can I exclude 'photo' posts being fetched by the taxonomy archive loop by updating my existing function?

```
function my_breakfast_query ( $query ) {
// not an admin page and is the main query
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
if (is_tax( 'food', 'breakfast' )){
  $tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
         'field' => 'id',
         'terms' => array( 366 )
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'food',
         'field' => 'id',
         'terms' => array( 364 )
    )
  );
  $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
 }
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_breakfast_query' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this myself. It returns the default post type posts instead of excluding the custom post type which is fine for my needs.

```
function my_breakfast_query ( $query ) {
// not an admin page and is the main query
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
if (is_tax( 'food', 'breakfast' )){
  $tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 366 )
     ),
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'food',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 364 )
     )
  );
  $query->set('post_type','post'); // Added this line to get a working solution
  $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
 }
 return $query; // Added this line to get a working solution
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_breakfast_query' );
```

Comment: Please provide the code in your **answer**...